# redefinition; previous definition was 'typedef' error

Tags: c, enums, typedef, redefinition

I got the following error:

> error C2365: 'DECIMAL' : redefinition; previous definition was 'typedef'

for the following definition in the header file:

```
enum DATA_TYPE {DECIMAL, HEXA, STRING};
```

I understood that this error occur by duplicate definitions, but there isn't another known defintion like that, and there aren't including files in this header file.

Which other reasons can cause that error?

Comment: Somebody else in your project or the headers you include is doing something like `typedef float DECIMAL`.  You should maybe choose a different name.

Comment: Looks like you have used `typedef` to create an alias `DECIMAL` for a type somewhere. You should show us more code.

Comment: See the output of `gcc -E file.c` - it will be helpful. You are including some header file that defines the alias `DECIMAL` in a `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your included header files, or the files they include ad infinitum, there is a definition of DECIMAL as a typedef.

Do not go looking for it! Well, do if you really want to but you aren't going to be able to do anything about it. Just rename your enum to something sensible like DT_DECIMAL.

If you really want to keep using DECIMAL and avoid this error there are two strategies. One is to use namespaces, to put your names into a different namespace from that other pesky definition.

The other (old school) way is to use a masking macro definition.